# how to kill and create the new image at same port using threading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, port

This code is reading images from socket using threads in parallel using background worker. i want to just reuse the same sockets for my new coming image again but the following error occurs .

****ERROR : The process can not access the file "D:\image 1.png because it is being used by another process ****

**i.e my idea is to kill the previous process and start a new process in the same socket .**

```
enter code here
```

namespace ScreenCapture
   {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String ipaddress;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ipaddress=textBox1.Text;
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ipaddress, 5000);                                  // create the client socket and connect to port number 5000
            Stream s = client.GetStream();                                                      // create the object of stream and assign client socket stream
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
            sw.AutoFlush = true;                                                                // auto flush the stream writer
            sw.WriteLine("Send");
            client.Close();
            s.Close();
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ipaddress, 5001);                                  // create the client socket and connect to port number 5000
                Stream s = client.GetStream();                                                      // create the object of stream and assign client socket stream
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                sw.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                client.Close();
                s.Close();

                Thread proces = new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    int portno = 5001 + i;
                    int j = i;
                //    MessageBox.Show(portno.ToString());
                    TcpClient clientt = new TcpClient(ipaddress,portno);                                // create client socket and connect to prot number 5000   
                    using (var stream = clientt.GetStream())                                            // create the stream variable
                    using (var output = File.Create("D:\\img"+j+".png"))           // create variable output
                    {
                        var buffer = new byte[1024];                                                    // crfeate variable buffer of length 1024
                        int bytesRead;
                        while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)                 // get the number of bytes from stream and greater then
                        {
                            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(j);
                    clientt.Close();
                    return;
                });
                proces.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(5200);

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());
            }

            if (i == 9)
                i = 0;
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.SuspendLayout();
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"D:\\img" +e.ProgressPercentage + ".png");
       if (File.Exists(@"D:\\img" + (e.ProgressPercentage - 1).ToString() + ".png"))
        {
           File.Delete(@"D:\\img" + (e.ProgressPercentage - 1).ToString() + ".png");
        }
        this.ResumeLayout();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

}

Comment: you need to close your output object using output.Close(); just after clientt.Close();

Comment: i did what you said but still the same error ...

Comment: What is the stacktrace from the error i.e. what line does it occur on? Also your code write to D:\img1.png not D:\image 1.png so I don't know where that error is coming from ... Also why do you have 5200 ms sleep I didn't notice that the first time round ...

Comment: the error comes at this line .
 using (var output = File.Create("D:\\img"+j+".png")) ...
sorry i quoted the wrong error message .
"error:The process can not access the file "D:\image1.png because it is being used by another process"
in my project my scope is to share the screen of android mobile on desktop. so basically i am making two apps desktop n mobile. i am using this sleep because to read the image from server(mobile) port.

Comment: That error message occurs when you haven't closed the file correctly or another process is accessing the file. There are free tools online which can tell you which process is "locking" the file. Maybe it's some other process? As for you putting in a 5.2 second sleep, this is really not the correct way to do it. If it takes less that 5.2 seconds you are needlessly waiting, if it takes more your code will have problems.

Comment: what could be a correct way of doing it ?
how screenshots can be shared in faster speed on pc . any idea ??

Comment: Sending screenshots would generally been done using some file transfer protocol for example ftp or sftp. If you are proposing some remote desktop then you would need to either develop some kind of rdp type protocol or use one that already exists. Rdp protocols normally don't send screenshots as this is very slow they would only send what has changed on the screen and a key frame every X frames. They also more than likely use some compression when sending the data. From your code if it takes 5.2 seconds (approx) to send a screenshot via a socket you'll be getting 0.2 frames per second ...

Comment: ... which is fairly unusable for any user.

Comment: i started screen sharing but problem is that each screenshot takes about 5 to 6 seconds to send it to desktop applications .very annoying .did too much work and still this response .

Comment: can i use rdp protocol to send screenshots from my android mobile application to desktop application with say 2 frames per second ?

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/ ?

Comment: @TheKingDave thanx for ur time u are giving me. one thing else i have to do is to handle the apps like i can type the message from the laptop and send and the same operations to be performed on mobile too . any idea about it ? airdroid do this but they don't share screen . here problem is there is lag in the screen share so how to handle the apps ...